# Centering contents within a div. Margin 0, auto does not work. Neither does display:inline

Tags: html, css

Hi I'm trying to center the 4 images in the div.  As you can see they're stuck on the left.

[image]

I would like them to be perfectly centre justified with at least a 5-10px margin surrounding them  (moved slightly to the right).
It's only this section I'm concerned about...not the rest of the HTML site.  Thanks.
My html is:

```
   <section id="slide-6" class="homeSlide">
    <div class="bcg">
        <div class="hsContainer">
           <!-- <div class="hsContent">-->


                         <div class="img">
  <a target="_blank" href="">
    <img src="http://fieldtelecommunications.com/images/telecommunications_equipment.jpg" alt="Klematis" width="280" height="280">
  </a>
                                        </div>

                                         <div class="img">
  <a target="_blank" href="">
    <img src="http://fieldtelecommunications.com/images/telecommunications_equipment.jpg" alt="Klematis" width="280" height="280">
  </a>
                                        </div>

                                         <div class="img">
  <a target="_blank" href="">
    <img src="http://fieldtelecommunications.com/images/telecommunications_equipment.jpg" alt="Klematis" width="280" height="280">
  </a>
                                        </div>

                                         <div class="img">
  <a target="_blank" href="">
    <img src="http://fieldtelecommunications.com/images/telecommunications_equipment.jpg" alt="Klematis" width="280" height="280">
  </a>
                                        </div>




                                </div>


</div>
</div>
</section>
```

Css is:

```
#slide-6 .bcg {
position: relative;
background-color: #efefef;
height:50%;
}
slide-6 .hsContent {
        position: relative;
}
slide-6 .hscontainer {

        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
         display:inline;
        overflow: hidden;


         margin: 0 auto; position: relative;
}

div.img {
    margin: 20px;
    /*padding: 5px;*/
    /*border: 1px solid #0000ff;*/
    /*height: auto;
    width: auto;*/
   /*float: left;*/
   display:inline;


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `text-align: center` to this div `#slide-6`

```
div.img {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 20px;
}
```

and on parent div

`text-align: center`

Answer (score 2):

Using a grid system like [960gs](http://960.gs) will make your life easier.
Otherwise you'll have to put the images in containers with width: 25%, 0 margin and 0 padding. You can set margins and paddings on the contents of the containers though. OR make the hsContainer fixed width and give it margin: auto;

Answer (score 2):

Your wrapper needs a `width` with `margin:0 auto` in order for the inner content to be aligned center.

```
section {margin:0 auto;width:1290px;}
```

[**JsFiddle** **Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/3bsbzda1/)

Answer (score 2):

one way to just encapsulate everything within

```
<center></center>
```

heres a fiddle :)

https://jsfiddle.net/qcoavm5r/

Comment: The <center> element was deprecated in HTML as it defines the presentation of its contents and doesn't describe its contents.

Answer (score 2):

Provide text-align:center to the parent element 'hsContainer'. This property will center align the elements inside it.

Answer (score 1):

Try `display: inline-block:` instead only block.